# Publishing an intuitive idea from outside academia

Tags: independent-researcher, publishability

I've written up an idea about how the web can be better organized that I think is an important one, and which can be grasped at an intuitive level. However, I lack the resources to conclusively prove its validity and utility, given that it is in the field of Web Sciences, and I don't have access to the necessary tools and techniques to go about experimentally verifying my idea.

How do I best go about pushing out this write-up? My options, as far as I can tell are:

- Contact a full-time academic researcher who lives in the same city as me, and who works in this field
- Try and publish this on my own (but where?)

Because of the intuitive appeal of the idea, I may not do too badly by pursuing option 2, but I'd like to know the pros and cons of pursing each option before I take a step either way.

Comment: The key point to note is that ideas on their own aren't research - you have to do the hard work to verify your ideas before anyone in academia will take them seriously. If you don't have the resources to do that work, finding someone else to help with that may not be a bad option (they'll want authorship, assuming they think the idea is good enough to spend their time on), but there's little academic value in simply publishing unverified musings (you thinking it's important doesn't count as sufficient verification). Outside academia, you can of course put what you like on the web :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I guess option 1 makes more sense then.

Comment: Yes, probably a good plan - as a suggestion, you may want to put together some decent initial justifications for why you think it's a good idea before you go and talk to them. Most researchers are very busy, and there's rarely a shortage of good ideas in academia, so you've got a sales job to do (you're basically asking someone to drop their project in favour of yours, so yours had better be good). The more work you can do on it yourself before trying to sell it to someone else, the more credible it will be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience doing this, so my answer should be taken with a bag of salt. What I have experience with is taking an idea from a different field than mine, and doing a few years of research, then publishing.

The first step, before you go and contact any academic, is to find yourself some good academic library (sci-hub if you are in a country like mine where knowledge is frowned upon). Then spend one or two months searching for research related to your idea. Chances are, if you are not a specialist in that field, that someone else already published something close to what you're thinking.

If you've already done that, and your idea has not been explored yet, do some more research to bring it into a form you can present to someone. Then think about contacting an academic in that field.

I would personally go on the friends and family route first. It should be the easiest. One of them could introduce you to a student/postdoc/faculty they know who can introduce you to someone who is a specialist in the field of your interest. Then you go to that person, discuss your idea, and see where it goes from there. Alternatively, if your job is related to the field of your idea, you could ask colleagues who have contact with academia to introduce you to someone who could help. The reason I'm suggesting this is that most researchers won't make time for a stranger, but they would reluctantly make time for their friends, or friends of friends. This is also a good reason not to expect them to talk to you for more than half an hour during your first meeting.

Then you explain your idea to those people. You should not expect they would be interested, and, if they are not, you should not push it. They may tell you that has been done already, or it couldn't be done because of some serious reasons. If that happens, you should not be disappointed.

If your idea really is good, you could ask them if they could help you in some way with the resources to pursue it. Do not expect them to be able to. Their own research has higher priority and they might have little time. But, if your idea is worth pursuing, they will either help you themselves or put you in touch with someone who can.

There are many people who try to contact academics to help get their ideas published. Most of those people think they can prove Einstein was wrong and Moon landing didn't happen. They often act arrogant and pushy, so academics usually ignore them. Every now and then, there is someone genuine among those people. Academics ignore them, too, because they behave the same. But, if you are sure you have a good idea, be persistent and do your research as well as you can with your current resources. When you eventually get to talk to someone in academia, present your idea succinctly, using the proper scientific terminology. They would at least listen to it.